# Direct link to Gmail Compose in full screen mode

Tags: gmail

I want to bookmark direct link to GMail compose page in full screen mode. The current link I found `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new` opens it but I have to press full screen button manually.

Anyway to get it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to select the option `Default to full screen` from your new mail window, like in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe I missed such a simple thing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is!

The solution I found was from this website: https://gsuitetips.com/tips/gmail/use-a-bookmark-to-send-a-customised-gmail-message/

1. Copy the link down bellow
2. Open a notepad window and change "your_email@here.com" to your desired email.
3. Open a new tab in your browser and paste the link you just created.
4. Hit enter.
5. When the website is loaded, add it to your bookmarks!

[copy this link -->] https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?fs=1&to=your_email@here.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&tf=cm